# How to use vba vlookup formula from two sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform, data-entry

I have two sheets first one called **Sheet8** is for the Main table that can be used by the Data Entry Form to enter the data in that table, and the second called **Sheet9** that includes the table for the vlookup. What I want is in the data entry user form as soon as I enter the Name the Discipline is created automatically based on that name.

Screenshot of the Data Entry for the Main table in sheet8

[image]

Screenshot of the sheet9 Table

[image]

> The code for Save Button

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8")
Dim n As Long

n = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Unprotect "1234"

sh.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
sh.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtName.Value
sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtProjNo.Value
sh.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtProjTitle.Value
sh.Range("E" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtBVEntity.Value
sh.Range("F" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtZIG.Value
sh.Range("G" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtSpenthrs.Value
sh.Range("H" & n + 1).Value = Me.comboCategory.Value
sh.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtDiscipline.Value
sh.Range("J" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtSCV.Value
sh.Range("K" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtTotSCV.Value
sh.Range("L" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtCotMER.Value
sh.Range("M" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtBudgethrs.Value
sh.Range("N" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtBudget.Value
sh.Range("O" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtProgress.Value
sh.Range("P" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtEndDate.Value


sh.Protect "1234"
```

> The code for the Name textbox

```
Private Sub txtName_AfterUpdate()

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet9.Range("C:D"), Me.txtName.Value) = 0 Then
MsgBox "This Name is Invalid."
Me.txtName.Value = ""
Exit Sub
End If

With Me
.txtDiscipline = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txtName, Sheet9.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `.txtDiscipline.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup( ...`

Comment: well, =vlookup(entered_name,C3:D14,2,0) is a simple start. you could use index() with match() like this =index(D3:D14,match(entered_name,C3:C14,0)) to do the same. But why 4 in your vlookup in the code, or is that getting something else?

Comment: what is `Sheet9.Range("Lookup")`? Does it got 4 columns?

Comment: @Solar Mike, yes 4 is for the number of column which is D that starts at column=4.

Comment: I have two sheets, sheet8 for data entry which includes Names in column (B) and Disciplines in column (I) that based on sheet9 that includes name in col (B) and discipline in col (D) table, so once I write the name in data entry , the discipline is auto generated.

Comment: If you are looking in col C for the name and the result is in col D then it should be 2 not 4.

Comment: @Solar Mike, `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet9.Range("C3:D14"), Me.txtName.Value) = 0 Then
MsgBox "This Name is Invalid."
Me.txtName.Value = ""
Exit Sub
End IfWith Me                                                                                                .txtDiscipline.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txtName, Sheet9.Range("Lookup"), 2, 0)
End With`

I updated the code like this, but still there auto generated not shown, and there is an error occur says "Object Required"

Comment: @Solar Mike, can you check please for me what can I do to avoid this error? Thanks

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns , I have two sheets, sheet8 for data entry which includes Names in column (B) and Disciplines in column (I) that based on sheet9 that includes name in col (C) and discipline in col (D) table, so once I write the name in data entry , the discipline is auto generated. Actually it should be 3 which is the col number (C) in sheet9